# Create a custom route for a collection using GET method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I do not manage to create a custom route for a collection, my entity is named File.

here is my Entity annotation :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"file"},"enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"file-write-customers"},"enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     attributes={"force_eager"=false},
 *     itemOperations={
 *           "get",
 *           "put",
 *           "get_mandate_pdf"={
 *                   "method"="POST",
 *                   "path"="/files/{id}/mandate-pdf",
 *                   "controller"=FileCreatePdfController::class,
 *                  },
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "stats"={
 *                   "method"="GET",
 *                   "path"="/files/stats",
 *                   "controller"=FileStatsController::class,
 *            }
 *     },
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"status": "exact", "sponsor": "exact"})
 * @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"updatedAt"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cases")
 */
```

The controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\File;

class FileStatsController
{

    public function __invoke(File $data): File
    {
        return $data;
    }

}
```

however i have this error when i reach /files/stats, it seems that api plaform is expecting an Id .
For some reasons if i switch the method from GET to POST the route is working

```
{
  "@context": "\/contexts\/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "The identifier id is missing for a query of App\\Entity\\File",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "\/srv\/api\/vendor\/doctrine\/orm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ORM\/ORMException.php",
      "line": 309,
      "args": []
    },
```

Comment: It looks like your controller action for your get route "FileStatsController::class"
need a "id" to get your entity from your repository, at least that is what the doctrine message says.
$yourRepository->find(NULL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the solution , in my Controller if i remove the typed variable $data

namespace App\Controller;

```
class FileStatsController
{

    public function __invoke($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

}
```

I manage to properly retreive the data

in addition, the method get is mandatory in the ApiRessource annotations

```
collectionOperations={
            "get",
 *          "stats"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *                   "path"="/stats",
 *                   "controller"=FileStatsController::class,
 *          }
 *     }
```